# Add column in MySQL view from PIVOT table (working with Laravel 5)

Tags: php, mysql, view, pivot-table

I have a table, call "estates", and four pivot tables for some characteristics, like a list of amenities, intallations, etc.

When I want to make a search (estates has about 200 fields and five multiselect) I use a view called "westates" to make faster search. But when I have to search for other characteristics I'm using four foreach (PHP) and I am crossing all results and compare with pivot table:
- $models are the result of the first query.

```
    $extras = $request->ms_extras_amenities; //Items selected in multiselect
    $others = $request->ms_more_features;
    $facilities = $request->ms_other_installations;
    $lapse = $request->lapse;

    $models = $models->filter(function($model) use ($lapse,$extras,$others,$facilities)
    {
        $haslapse = false;
        if(count($lapse)){
            foreach($lapse as $item){
                $result = \DB::table('rent_period_estates')
                    ->whereRaw("estates_id = $model->id AND rent_period_id = $item")
                    ->count();
                if($result != 0) $haslapse = true;
            }
        }
        else
            $haslapse = true;

        $hasextras = true;
        if(count($extras)){
            foreach($extras as $extra){
                $result = \DB::table('extras_amenities_estates')
                    ->whereRaw("estates_id = $model->id AND extras_id = $extra")
                    ->count();
                if($result == 0) $hasextras = false;
            }
        }

        $hasothers = true;
        if(count($others)) {
            foreach ($others as $other) {
                $result = \DB::table('other_chara_estates')
                    ->whereRaw("estates_id = $model->id AND other_chara_id = $other")
                    ->count();
                if ($result == 0) $hasothers = false;
            }
        }
        $hasfacilities = true;
        if(count($facilities)) {
            foreach ($facilities as $facility) {
                $result = \DB::table('other_facilities_estates')
                    ->whereRaw("estates_id = $model->id AND other_facilities_id = $facility")
                    ->count();
                if ($result == 0) $hasfacilities = false;
            }
        }
    //Estate have to have all items selected in the multiselectd fields
        if ($hasothers && $hasextras && $hasfacilities && $haslapse){
            return $model;
        }
    });
```

Now I have right results, but testing with 7 states I'd make near 300 queries.

I want to know how I can create the view including in order the pivot entries comma separated as text (it's an idea), like getting results in a array, implode it in order ([2,1,8,4] to "1,2,4,8") in a field in my view, so when I make a query I can make only one query adding:
    ... AND (westates.others = $model->others AND westates.extras = $model->extras AND ...)

May be a Procedure can do it in the MySQL server, but really I can`t find a solution.

Here's the view:

```
    "CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW westates AS
            SELECT
                concat(estates.locale,estates.id) as code,
                cities.name as city,
                councils.name as council,
                states.name as state,
                countries.name as country,
                concat(cities.name,' (',councils.name,')') as city_council,
                estates.*

            FROM estates
                JOIN countries  ON (estates.country_id = countries.id)
                JOIN states     ON (estates.state_id = states.id)
                JOIN councils   ON (estates.city_council_id = councils.id)
                JOIN cities     ON (estates.city_id = cities.id)"
```